# Codeigniter 2.1 - upload images first and then create gallery in db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need some advice how can I do following:
I made script that uploads images via HTML5 drag and drop function and it is working. I want to create system where user drop images for upload (and they are uploaded), write name and description of the gallery and upon clicking submit, there needs to be a function that will create gallery, give id and give that id to the images and transfer images to designated folder (name of the gallery) . At the moment I don't have idea how can I do this. Also if user decides not to create gallery, images that are uploaded needs to be deleted (I guess this can be done via cron job ).

DB for gallery is following:

```
gallery
    id_gallery
    name
    description
    date_created

gallery_images
    id_image
    gallery_id
    path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to move the files to another folder. Doesn't matter where they live so long as the application can find them (see: `path`).

What was the plan for the db you have? You show the schema but mention you don't have any idea how to use it?

Anyway... if you added an `active` field to the gallery table, you could then mark it as active on submit.

```
gallery
    id_gallery int
    name text
    description text
    date_created date
    active default 0

gallery_images
    id_image int
    gallery_id int
    path text
```

provided that you instantiate a gallery when the first image is uploaded (or at some point) and insert a row into gallery_images for each image uploaded, you could submit like so:

```
function submit_gallery($id = NULL, $active = NULL)
{
    if($id AND $active === 1)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('gallery', array('active' => 1));
    }

    //could have a "cancel" button call this. or use a cron job
    elseif($id AND $active === 0)
    {

        $this->db->where('gallery_id', $id);
        $imgs = $this->db->get('gallery_images');

        foreach($imgs->result() as $img)
        {
            //delete the img files
            unlink($img->path);
        }

        $this->db->where('gallery_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('gallery_images');

    }
}
```

Comment: This method work when gallery is created on first image upload, but in my case user is uploading images first (drag and drop them) and then (after writing data about gallery) he click **Create Gallery**. This way images are uploaded before image is created. At the moment I am experimenting with another table which will temporary contain images and upon creating gallery, data from that table will be copied to **gallery_images** and deleted from the temporary table.